# How to split existing partitions

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I have multiple partitions on my table as below.

Partition- Day_20190509 with high value of 20190510
Partition- Day_20190520 with high value of 20190521
Partition- Day_99999999 with MAXVALUE as high.

I want to create three new partitions for Day_20190510,Day_20190513,Day_20190514 with high values as 20190513,20190514,20190520 respectively.

I believe this can done using SPLIT partitions but could not understand how I can create partitions in between. Can someone assist with the query for this?

I tried using partition split option but could not understand what will be my range part and new partitions

```
ALTER TABLE table_name SPLIT PARTITION partition_name
  AT (range_part_value)
  INTO 
  (
    PARTITION new_part1 
      [TABLESPACE tablespace_name],
    PARTITION new_part2 
      [TABLESPACE tablespace_name]
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Values you described as high values (20190513,20190514,20190520) in new partitions (Day_20190510,Day_20190513,Day_20190514) belong to the current partition: Day_20190520 (Value range: 20190511 - 20190521)

So current partition Day_20190520 must be split as follows:

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name SPLIT PARTITION Day_20190520 INTO 
  (PARTITION Day_20190510 VALUES LESS THAN (20190514), -- 20190513 + 1
   PARTITION Day_20190513 VALUES LESS THAN (20190515), -- 20190514 + 1
   PARTITION Day_20190514 VALUES LESS THAN (20190521), -- 20190520 + 1
   PARTITION Day_20190520_1);
```

Hope this will solve your problem.